# How to get / determine the optimal combination (s, S) in this model using simulation?

Tags: model, julia, combinations, simulation

How to get / determine the optimal combination (s, S) in this model using simulation?

```
using Distributions

function simulateOneRun(m, s, S)
pd = Poisson(20)
h, c = 0.1, 2.0 # storage cost & sale price
p = 0.50 # probability of delivery
K, k = 40.0, 1.0 # fixed and variable order cost
Xj, Yj = S, 0.0 # stock in the morning and in the evening
profit = 0.0 # cumulated profit.
for  j in 1:m
    Yj = Xj - rand(pd) # subtract demand for the day.
    Yj < 0.0 && (Yj = 0.0) # lost demand.
    profit += c * (Xj - Yj) - h * Yj
    if Yj < s && rand()< p # we have a successful order.
        profit -= K + k * (S - Yj)
        Xj = S
    else
        Xj = Yj
    end
end
profit / m
end

for S in [190.0, 200.0, 210.0]
println(S,"\t", @time simulateOneRun(10_000_000, 100.0, S))
end
```

I do not know how to determine the optimal caching of this function.

Answer (score 1):

This question is rather related to simulation optimization algorithms and not directly to programming. The crucial issue is what is the domain of `(s,S)` pair, as it will influence the algorithm. Probably you can have a look e.g. at this [handbook](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781493913831) to select an approach appropriate in your case. Also, because the problem is stochastic, note that the solution will be found only with some probability of correct selection (assuming that `(s, S)` space has small cardinality, in continuous spaces PCS-based reasoning does not apply).

In order to reduce the computational burden (lower `m` in your code) you will probably want to use some variance reduction approach (see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance_reduction)), in which case for each consumer of randomness in your code you should provide a separate and reproducible stream for random numbers. This is an example how you could modify your code to get it:

```
using Random

function simulateOneRun(m, s, S, seed1=1234, seed2=4321)
    mt1 = MersenneTwister(seed1)
    mt2 = MersenneTwister(seed2)
    pd = Poisson(20)
    h, c = 0.1, 2.0 # storage cost & sale price
    p = 0.50 # probability of delivery
    K, k = 40.0, 1.0 # fixed and variable order cost
    Xj, Yj = S, 0.0 # stock in the morning and in the evening
    profit = 0.0 # cumulated profit.
    for  j in 1:m
        Yj = Xj - rand(mt1, pd) # subtract demand for the day.
        Yj < 0.0 && (Yj = 0.0) # lost demand.
        profit += c * (Xj - Yj) - h * Yj
        if Yj < s && rand(mt2) < p # we have a successful order.
            profit -= K + k * (S - Yj)
            Xj = S
        else
            Xj = Yj
        end
    end
    profit / m
end
```

You might also consider pre-allocating the random streams for the demand and order success in a vector like this `demand = rand(pd, 10_000_000)` and `success = rand(10_000_000) .< p` and pass them to `simulateOneRun`. This should speed it up a bit, but the gain will probably not be large.

This is not a final solution as you still need to modify the code to perform a correct assessment of the performance of the system in steady state (as I guess this is the assignment you have). [This book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0073401323) is a good reference here.